# How to keep the user logged in, in Swift (iOS)?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication

I am making an app that initially asks the user to log in, and on successful login.. takes the user to their dashboard. But, now, when I close the app.. I want the user to be logged in and the app to directly open from their dashboard, and not the login page. How do I do it?

[Please see the link (gif), as I'm not able to show it here because it's my first question on stackoverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN1BR.gif)

P.S. I'm new to iOS, I did surf internet and found something "UserDefaults".. but everything on it, included the use of navigation controller in the storyboard.. I'm not using any navigation controller.. but simply using a "show" segue for transition to the user dashboard.

[My storyboard image, segue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9G0r.png)

Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of a navigation controller does not affect the user defaults. Anywhere in the app, you can call

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
```

You can then write to defaults by calling

```
defaults.setValue(value, forKey: "key")
```

And later retrieve this value by doing

```
let savedValue = default.value(forKey: "key")
```

Depending on what you're using for login, you will need to decide what needs to be saved and retrieved, and where and when that needs to happen

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with using `UserDefaults`, however, `UserDefaults` are easily accessible and are not safe. You would need to find a secure solution in case you are storing sensitive data (such as token). `CoreData` would be an option if you want to store data securely.

A third option would be to store the token in `Keychain`. This is also a secure method. The advantage is that the same token can be used by all of your apps (by the same developer) and the token persists even if the app is removed/re-installed.